# Converting POSIXct or POSIXt to character results in a very large value in R

Tags: r

I'm having a bit of a weird issue.

```
x <- Sys.time()
x <- character(x)
```

This for some reason throws an error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.9 Gb".

I faced a similar issue recently: I'm running code that accumulates information to a dataframe. Usually, this dataframe is about 6 MB. Today, this same dataframe from the same code is over 44 MB.

I'm new to parallel computing in R. Both these issues arose after I used doParallel and foreach so I'm guessing this has to do with one of these.

The parallelized segment looks like this:

```
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores() - 1)

  <foreach code>

  stopImplicitCluster()
```

However, only the issue with the dataframe is related to this segment.

```
x <- Sys.time()
x <- character(x)
```

This still throws an error saying the character vector is too big even when I'm not running this part of the code (or even in a new R session).

Could my parallel code have changed something about how R behaves (permanently)?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `as.character` instead of `character`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to convert to `character`, it should be

```
as.character(x)
```

Or wrap with `strftime` which can also take `format`, `tz` arguments

```
strftime(Sys.time())
```

But, `character(n)` returns an blank vector of length 'n'.  As `Sys.time` is stored as double, it will be coerced to a numeric value and that many times the `""` is repeated i.e.

```
as.integer(Sys.time())
#[1] 1593382112
```

---

In my system, it returns something like

```
# ....
#99937] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" #"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
#[99985] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
# [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1593281954 entries ]


character(5)
#[1] "" "" "" "" ""
```

According to `?character`, the usage is

> character(length = 0)

where

> length - A non-negative integer specifying the desired length. Double values will be coerced to integer: supplying an argument of length other than one is an error